# 3d effects in android and Iphone

Tags: java, android, objective-c, iphone, intel

We have a lot of days of research but can't find a solution for the following project.  We need to convert a flux project to IOS and android native app. But as flux supports flash scripting it has easily implementing some 3d effects like shadow, emboss gradient etc. Please check the link [here](http://projects.zoondia.org/signfabcreator/signCreator.swf)  for seeing the swf file we have. We need to convert all this features into a native IOS and android app. We have research some area and found that most of the item we can implement except one icon here. The fourth icon have some 3d effects, shadow effects, border, emboss, contour and gradient etc. Can anybody check on this and guide us whether this can be implemented in IOS and android. I am pasting the entire url here again http://projects.zoondia.org/signfabcreator/signCreator.swf. Please check and let me know if this is possible. Let me if this is possible or not. If yes it will be helpful for me if anybody can give me a clue about implementing those in both android and ios

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting! But I'm afraid you have to reimplement all this functionality by yourself. Don't be upset. There are good news for you - OpenGL ES and GLSL are extremely portable. So you can reuse 100% of your shaders. What is even better now you can share the other code too and stay native. Not long ago Intel announced the [Multi-OS Engine](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-inde-multi-os-early-access). It enables you to develop native mobile applications for iOS and Android with Java. There are a bunch of tutorials inside installation package. One of them is especially dedicated to cross-platform OpenGL capabilities. Please check out my [OpenGLBox sample](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-inde-multi-os-engine-opengl-sample).

Comment: Yah the library is very helpful for the game development. But we are not seeing any library that help to put some 3d effects on the given input text.

Comment: Thanks llya for the reply. I am contacting the intel team for the installation and sdks for checking it. I will check it.